# unable to run android application on device from titanium studio same on eclipse

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

my mobile  has more than GB Spaces on storage device.

eclipse Android and titanium studio

how to run on device instead emulator.

i got below error on titanium as well on eclipse.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the right answer but I experienced the same problem while working with titanium on my device. I solved it by deleting the previous build every time I ran the project. I hope titanium fixes this issue or someone really answers why does it happen!

Comment: no luck, in titanium documentation then mentioned, this kind is known issue.